# How do I get databinding to work with null class?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I am developing a WPF application that is pretty much an application form.  It has multiple text fields.  This is my first application I am doing using the MVVM model so I am sure I am missing something. I have a lot of textboxes so the code I show will concentrate on four text field, the fourth field is suppose to total as the other three change.  However the databinding I have is not executing.  I cannot figure out why when I type a number into the textbox txbFamO the FamilyO get statement is not executed.  Am I not binding correctly?  Do I not have the class Applicant initialized correctly?

Here is my XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ApplicationForm.Views.ApplicationView" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ApplicationForm"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:ApplicationForm.Model"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:ApplicationForm.Views"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:ApplicationForm.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="1100" Width="800" Background="#FFDAFDF2">

<Grid x:Name="grdAppForm">
    <Grid x:Name="grdAppFormGrid" DataContext="{Binding Applicant}"
          Height="881" Width="700" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <Label x:Name="lblFamilySize" Content="Family Size:" Height="28" Width="102" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="372,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" />
        <Label x:Name="lblFamO" Content="O:" Height="28" Width="27" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="471,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txbFamO" Text="{Binding FamilyO, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="22" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="496,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" 
                 FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblFamA" Content="A:" Height="28" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="516,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbxFamA" Text="{Binding FamilyA, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Height="22" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="541,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" 
                 FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblFamC" Content="C:" Height="28" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="562,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtFamC" Text="{Binding FamilyC, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 Height="22" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="587,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" BorderBrush="Black" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblEqual" Content="=" Height="28" Width="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               Margin="611,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbxFamTot" Text="{Binding FamilyTotal, 
                Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" IsReadOnly="True" Height="22" Width="30" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="634,71,0,0" FontFamily="Arial" 
                FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0,0,0,3" IsTabStop="False" 
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

My Model Code:

```
namespace ApplicationForm.Model
{
public class ApplicationModel
{
}


public class Applicant : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string familyO;
    private string familyA;
    private string familyC;

    public string FamilyO
    {
        get { return familyO; }

        set
        {
            if (familyO != value)
            {
                familyO = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyO");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyTotal");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FamilyA
    {
        get { return familyA; }

        set
        {
            if (familyA != value)
            {
                familyA = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyA");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyTotal");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FamilyC
    {
        get { return familyC; }

        set
        {
            if (familyC != value)
            {
                familyC = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyC");
                RaisePropertyChanged("FamilyTotal");
            }
        }
    }

    public string FamilyTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return (Convert.ToInt16(familyO) + Convert.ToInt16(familyA) + Convert.ToInt16(familyC)).ToString();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
}
```

}

My ViewModel Code:

```
namespace ApplicationForm.ViewModel
{
class ApplicationViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
    // at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-dotnet-quickstart.json
    static string[] Scopes = { SheetsService.Scope.Spreadsheets };
    static string ApplicationName = "NB Food Pantry Application";


    public RelayCommand LoadApplicantCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelayCommand ClearDataCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelayCommand PrintApplicantCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public RelayCommand CloseCommand
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public Applicant applicants;





    public ApplicationViewModel()
    {
        applicants = new Applicant();
        PrintApplicantCommand = new RelayCommand(PrintApplicant);
        ClearDataCommand = new RelayCommand(ClearApplicantData);
        CloseCommand = new RelayCommand(CloseApp);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Applicant> Applicants
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: _"the code I show will concentrate on four text field"_ -- the code you show should be **minimal**. Surely it does not take _four_ text boxes, plus all the other stuff, just to demonstrate whatever issue it is you're having. Please read [mcve]. See also [ask], and especially the articles linked at the bottom of that page. That said, it does appear that you've completely failed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `ApplicationViewModel` class. And I don't see a single `Applicant` property anywhere. Did you look at the debug output to see what binding errors are present?

Comment: And what is _"a null class"_ supposed to mean anyway?

Comment: How did I fail to implement INotifyPropertyChanged? My ApplicationViewModel has INotifyPropertyChanged in its definition, have RaisePropertyChanged in my setters. In my XAML I set the datacontext to my Applicant class and set bindings on the class fields for the appropriate textboxes. When I step through the debugger the setter codes do not get called. I have a disconnect somewhere not sure where. I assume I'm not creating an instance of Applicant correctly at startup. I am not sure how to create an Applicant class the the bindings can use, all values at startup would be empty or null

Comment: _"My ApplicationViewModel has INotifyPropertyChanged in its definition, have RaisePropertyChanged in my setters"_ -- the former is true, the latter is not. All of the properties you show there are implicit implementations, e.g. `public RelayCommand LoadApplicantCommand { get; set; }`. _"In my XAML I set the datacontext to my Applicant class"_ -- no, you don't. You set your `DataContext` property to a non-existent `Applicant` property value. Again, **Did you look at the debug output to see what binding errors are present?** If you want help, you need to improve the code example in the question.

Comment: Where this property `Applicant` is present as used in ` DataContext="{Binding Applicant}"` ? And where it is populated ?

Answer (score -1):

I have figured out my issue.  I didn't create an instance of Applicants and initialize the elements.